# How does one show that the set $E = \{ y : y > 0, y^n < x \}$ is non-empty?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I was going through theorem 1.21 from Rudin (without looking at the proof) and I wanted to show that the supremum of $E = \{ y : y > 0, y^n < x \}$ must be the element that satisfies $y^n = x$. But for me to even attempt that next step, I need to show that $E$ is non-empty (then I need to show its bounded) so that I can show a supremum exists (so that I can use the least upper bound LUB property of R). However, I've been stuck for a couple of hours on this.

It feels really obvious it should exist. If people can provide **hints** first before telling me the answer, that would be super helpful!

---

I wrote this and realized I did have a very ugly proof. Any help making it more concise would be helpful! (since its such an obvious idea that there must be a simpler proof that makes this fact look obvious...or at least I believe thats true).

I can share what I've thought (but hasn't helped me so far):

I considered first the case when $x>1$. In this case it should be obvious that some element a little smaller than 1 should be enough to show $1 - \epsilon <  x^{1/n}$ (i.e. by showing instead $(1 - \epsilon)^n < x$).

Since $0< 1 - \epsilon < 1$ then raising it to the power of any natural number should decrease it size so:

$$ 0 < (1 - \epsilon)^n < 1 - \epsilon < 1 < x$$

which guarantees that $1 - \epsilon \in E$. So in this case $E$ is not empty it seems (since we choose $1 > \epsilon > 0$).

Now consider $x < 1$. In this case the easiest way to show $E$ is non-empty seems to me to show again that some "arbitrarily" small element close to 0 when raised to $n$ is smaller than $x$. So notice we have $0 < x < 1$. This is useful because we can invoke the fact that Q is dense in R by focusing on $0<x$. So between any reals there is a rational. Therefore, $\exists q \in Q$ s.t. $0<q<x$. Notice that $x<1$ so is $q$. Therefore, we have $0<q<x<1$. But raising $q$ to the power of anything decreases it (and since its not zero it can never go above it nor equal it), so we have $0<q^n<q<x$ . Thus in this case $E$ is also non-empty.

Notice that if $x=1$ then $y$ s.t. $y^n = x =1$ is just $y=1$ means we don't care about showing $E$ being empty (but it is cuz Q is dense in R and E would be bounded by 1 and 0).

If someone can help me make this proof shorter that would be useful! I feel that this fact is so obvious that it should have a proof that is much simpler and cleaner to explain (i.e. that makes this question obvious). If someone has one that would be useful!

Also, I hope my proof is not incorrect in anyway...

Comment: There is no reason to pick a rational number in your second argument. And also, why not combine both approaches, and just pick any $0 < y < \min(x,1)$? Then $0 < y^n < y < x$ no matter what $x$ is. (Rudin's explicit choice of $y$ actually does exactly that.)

Comment: @AlexProvost hmm, I choose a rational because I didn't know of any other mathematical fact besides that one to guarantee I could choose one. What did you have in mind instead? Not sure if I follow your suggestion fully.

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRomeroHinrichs sorry Francisco, I am not sure I follow why that would be true and even if it were (assume an oracle told me the truth), how would that complete the proof?

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRomeroHinrichs do you mind providing an answer to what you had in mind. I am curious now to see if there is any proof that doesn't rely on $t^n < t < x$ fact.

Comment: I just gazed at what I wrote there and it's not working that well. I'll erase it.
Why don't you want the $t^n < t < x $ fact ? It follows directly from $t < 1 \Rightarrow t^2  < t < 1  \Rightarrow \ldots$

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRomeroHinrichs oh no, Im fine with it, though all proofs relied on it and since you mentioned a different strategy I became very curious. But its ok I have nothing against it $t^n < t < 1$. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $x>0$, note that there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that ${1 \over m} < x$. Then ${1 \over m^n} \le {1 \over m}$ and
so ${1 \over m}$ is in the set.

Comment: Proving $m$ exists seems quintessential. I assume it exists because Q is dense in R? Or some type of reverse Archemedian property type of proof?

Comment: @Pinocchio: It follows from the completeness axiom.

Comment: sorry copper I am just learning about real analysis so I'm not familiar with the completeness axiom. But a quick google search seems to imply its equivalent to the Least Upper Bound property (LUB) which I am familiar with that. How does the LUB property imply such an m exists? I don't really see how thats true.

Comment: I had a different idea/proof for why your statement is true. From the denseness of Q in R, we know some rational exists between 0 and x. i.e. $0 < \frac{a}{b} < x$. Now notice that $bx - 0 = b(x-0)$ which is the distance from $bx$ to $b0=0$. If this distance is greater than 1 then a natural number must be contained, in particular if we have $bx > 1$ then $a=1$ must be contained in $[0,bx]$. Which is exactly what we want! But how do we know b exists? Simply by the Archemedia property, i.e. for any reals x < y there exists a natural k s.t. $ kx > y$. Which shows your $m$ exists.

Comment: @Pinocchio: The denseness comes from the completeness axiom.

Comment: I guess...though all of real analysis comes from the LUB property so not sure if thats the explanation I would use. Regardless, I just noticed that using the standard proof to the Archimedean property but swaping $x$ for $\frac{1}{x}$ completes the proof. Say, $\forall x \in R, \exists n \in N: n > x$ just use reciprocal of x instead of x.  Thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that I have to show there is a bijection between the reals and $1/x$...ughhh...

Answer (score 3):

If $ 1 < x $  then the point $y=1$ is in set. If $ 0< x \leq 1 $ then the point $\frac{x}{2}$ is in set.

Comment: The first one seems correct to me since since $1^n = 1$ and since $1<x$ then we have $1^n = 1 < x$ which shows $y^n < x$ which is the key fact. For your second suggestion by drawing pictures it seems obviously true but I think it requires a proof. Or at least explain why its right, in particular you need to show $\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^n < x$ which doesn't seem obvious to me in symbols.

Comment: I guess the argument would be that since raising to the power of $n$ any element less than 1 (<1), decreases it in size, so in particular $x^n < x$. Thus, we can obviously see $ \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^n = \frac{x^n}{2^n} < x^n < x $ which shows $ \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^n  < x $ as needed. Basically raising it to the n doesn't make it larger than x (since its smaller than 1) and further dividing it by 2 doesn't either make it larger than x.

Comment: If you multiply two positive number together which are less than one the result becomes strictly less than of each of them.  

If this is not clear for you, you can axiomatically prove it, it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Note for instance that if $a < b$ ($a,b$ any two real numbers), then their *average* $\frac{a+b}{2}$ lies between them: $a < \frac{a+b}{2} < b$. Indeed, it follows from adding $a$ (resp. $b$) to both sides of the original inequality to get $2a < a + b$ (resp. $a + b < 2b$) and multiplying both sides by $1/2$.

Now we can simply take the smallest number between $x$ and $1$, which we denote by $\min(x,1)$. And now it is clear that there is at least one $y$ satisfying $0 < y < \min(x,1)$, namely the average $\min(x,1)/2$. And so $0 < y^n < y < x$.

Comment: sorry for being dense, but how does your choice of $y = \frac{min(x,1)}{2}$ satisfy $\left( \frac{min(x,1)}{2} \right)^n < x$? Should this be obvious? I can't quite follow your argument. It seems that using the average came out of thin air...at least for me.

Comment: @Pinocchio $0 < y < \min(x,1) \leq 1$. Thus $ 0 < y < 1$, and so $0 < y^n < y$. Also, I used the average to show you that one doesn't need to invoke the denseness of the rationals to simply produce a number between two other numbers.

Comment: thats awesome! Is the reason to not invoke denseness of Q is to show there is a different just as intuitive proof?